# Plotting declared function with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'd like to declare this function:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[domain=0:8, scale=1.5,
 declare function={
  func(\x) ={-(1.44)*(\x)+0.6+\x}/{(0.8)*(\x)+0.3};
 }]
% draw axes 
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (3.5,0) node[above right] {\small$t$};
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (0,2.5) node[left] {$q_B (t)$};
\draw[red]   plot[domain=0:2.8] {func(\x)};
```

But Overleaf says "cannot parse this plotting data"
Why?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site! I think when you use `declare function` you shouldn't use curly braces for grouping in the function. That is, instead of `{...}/{...}` you should use `(...)/(...)`, or for your case `func(\x) = (-1.44*\x+0.6+\x)/(0.8*\x+0.3);`.

Second, instead of `plot {<function>}`, you need `plot (<x expression>, <y expression>)`, for your case `plot (\x, {func(\x)})`. You need the curly braces around the coordinate expressions that contain parentheses, otherwise the closing parenthesis is read as the end of the coordinate.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[domain=0:8, scale=1.5,
 declare function={
  func(\x) = (-1.44*\x+0.6+\x)/(0.8*\x+0.3);
 }]
% draw axes 
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (3.5,0) node[above right] {\small$t$};
      \draw[->] (0.0,0.0) -- (0,2.5) node[left] {$q_B (t)$};
\draw[red]   plot[domain=0:2.8] (\x,{func(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```